# Can the Robe of Eyes let you see into the Material Plane whilst on the Ethereal Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, vision-and-light, planes, ethereal-plane

I am running a home campaign and one of my characters is in possession of a [*robe of eyes*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-eyes). Part of the item's ability is that the wearer can see into the Ethereal Plane as they want out to 120 feet.

For the "seeing into the Ethereal Plane" part, I take it that they are talking from the point of view that the character is currently in the Prime Material Plane looking into the Ethereal Plane.

If that same character were **in** the Ethereal Plane, does the *robe of eyes* allow them to see into the Prime Material Plane the same way they'd be able to see into the Ethereal Plane if they were on the Material Plane?

Comment: The [dnd-5e] tag is the bit we're really after! Thanks. I reformatted your question a bit, and fleshed out the title; if you're not happy with my edits, please feel free to roll them back.

Comment: haha no that's perfect! Thank you for that! I was definitely having a tough time wording that properly >.<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The [Robe of Eyes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-eyes) does not help you see into the Material Plane

We know from the DMG on page 48 that:

> Visibility in the Border Ethereal is limited to 60 feet. The plane's depths comprise a region of swirling mist and fog called the Deep Ethereal, where visibility is limited to 30 feet.
> From the Border Ethereal, a traveler can see into whatever plane it overlaps, but that plane appears muted and indistinct, its colors blurring into each other and its edges turning fuzzy.

So only from the Border Ethereal, not the Deep Ethereal, can we see back into the Material Plane. The [Robe of Eyes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-eyes) only states:

> You can see invisible creatures and objects, as well as see into the Ethereal Plane, out to a range of 120 feet.

The Robe lacking a clause that allows you to see from the Deep Ethereal into the Material Plane means that it does not allow you to do so.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much for the clarification! I had a feeling but couldn't be sure, this is gonna really help me build out the next part of the adventure (planning on having them land in the ethereal plane when they cross through this portal they last ended in front of)